# ページネーションに｛・・・｝の省略記号を追加する方法

Tags: php, html, wordpress

ワードプレスでアーカイブページを作成し、
初めてページネイションを作成しています。

ダブルポストです。
（https://teratail.com/questions/ao0pmojgghzr8l）

ページネーションをワードプレスのプラグイン
WP-PageNaviを使い、また、プラグイン　Wp Pagenavi Styleをインストールし、
のデフォルトのデザインを編集しました。

コードは下記になります。

archive.php

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="list-box">
        <ul>
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'post', // ページの種類（例、page、post、カスタム投稿タイプ）
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 10, // 表示件数
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'DESC'  
        ) );
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            ?>
                <?php // ブログの一覧を表示する start ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="blog-list__list-item">
                    <div class="blog-list-category">
 

<?php
$undef_category = (count(get_the_category()) == 0) || in_category('1');
if($undef_category == true){
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   echo $category[0]->cat_name;
}else{             
  $category = get_the_category(); 
    echo $category[0]->cat_name."一覧";
}
?>
                    </div>
                        <div class="blog-list-wrapper-second"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image-second"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 148)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  
    
        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">
                <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                    <div class="blog-item-title-container">
                <?php
if ( mb_strlen( $post->post_title, 'UTF-8' ) > 20 ) {
  $title = mb_substr( $post->post_title, 0, 20, 'UTF-8' );
  echo $title . '…';
} else {
  echo $post->post_title;
}
?>
</a>
</div>
  <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
  <div class="blog-item-txt">
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>  
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?> 
            </div>    


                    </article>
                    <?php break; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="blog-list__list-item">                  
                        <div class="blog-list-category">    
                        <?php
$undef_category = (count(get_the_category()) == 0) || in_category('1');
if($undef_category == true){
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   echo $category[0]->cat_name;
}else{             
  $category = get_the_category(); 
    echo $category[0]->cat_name."一覧";
}
?>
    </div> 
<div class="blog-list-wrapper-second"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 179)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  

        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">               
         <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                <?php
if ( mb_strlen( $post->post_title, 'UTF-8' ) > 20 ) {
  $title = mb_substr( $post->post_title, 0, 20, 'UTF-8' );
  echo $title . '…';
} else {
  echo $post->post_title;
}
?></h3>
</a>
  <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
            
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
    
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>     

                       
                    </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                <?php // ブログの一覧を表示する end ?>
                <?php break; ?>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        else:
            echo '<div><p>ありません。</p></div>';
        endif;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $the_query)); ?>
</div>
```

css3_black.css

```
.wp-pagenavi {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 326px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wp-pagenavi a ,.wp-pagenavi span.pages, .wp-pagenavi span.extend {
        padding: 18px 19.75px 18px 19.75px !important;
        border: solid 1px #1B224C !important;
        border-radius: 3px !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
        color: #1b224c !important;
        margin-right: 19px !important;
        border-color: #1b224c !important;
        background-color:#FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
        border-color:#202020 !important;
        background:#525252 !important;
        color:#fff !important;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9F9F9F 1px,#6C6C6C 1px,#525252) !important;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,color-stop(0.02,#9F9F9F),color-stop(0.02,#6C6C6C),color-stop(1,#525252)) !important;

}
.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    padding: 18px 19.75px 18px 19.75px !important;
    border: solid 1px #DCDCDC !important;
    border-color: #1b224c !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-right: 19px !important;
    border-color: #1b224c !important;
    background-color: #1b224c;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
   }
   .wp-pagenavi {
    float: none !important;
}
```

下記写真には省略の｛・・・｝がありますが。
理想
[image: プラグインの画面（上）]

自作した下記写真には、ありません、

[image: プラグインの画面（下）]

どのようにすれば｛・・・｝を追加できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

https://shanabrian.com/web/jquery/pagination.php
上記サイトのやりかたに従って、一からやり直しました、
このやり方ですら、かなり苦戦をしていましたので、質問サイトに、どのように工夫したか回答があります、
このサイトを使用する方は、ご参考にしてみてください。